# Required to enter excess target.delay() in order to make UIAutomation work

Tags: instruments, ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I've recorded a number of scripts via Instruments and now when I replay them from the command line I find I need to excessively and manually add target.delay() to make them work.

Is this really how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

UI action tends to take some time to act on the application. Its better to add a minimum delay between consequent action to prevent instruments from skipping any action while playing.